# What does "plutonomy" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the word *plutonomy* mean?

Comment: Why don't you just look it up?

Comment: @Tim It is a strange question from man from Sweden. I want that people just think about it. In Russian "plut" means "swindler". Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's one [definition](http://www.wordnik.com/words/plutonomy):

> The science of wealth or riches.

or

> The study of the production and
>   distribution of wealth

and an example from [Progressive Bloggers](http://www.hollow-hill.com/sabina/2008/10/economy_ecologytheyre_closer_t.html):

> Including the disaster capitalists
>   who, in Naomi Klein's book, thought
>   that they could own the world and
>   simply jet away from all natural
>   disasters to some well-appointed,
>   **"plutonomy"** - friendly desert island.

Here's an 1854 excerpt from the Christian Remembrancer Volumes 27-28 page 459:

> Mr. Ludlow who is an uncompromising
>   advocate of the rights of labor,
>   observes: 'So longe, therefore, as
>   your competitive **plutonomy** confines
>   itself to its scientific field, to its
>   dead subject-matter of wealth, we
>   socialists have to listen to it and
>   learn from it

There's also a good definition and infographic about plutonomy in [pages 231-232 of George L. Fouke's Damn The Warocracy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982074417):

[image: http://bayimg.com/OAHLJAAdm plutonomy info and infographic from George L. Fouke's Damn the Warocracy pages 231 and 232]

hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 7):

It is a neologism suggesting an economy driven by or for the wealthiest (from the Greek *ploutos* meaning wealth).

[This](http://www.businessinsider.com/ajay-kapur-plutonomy-2011-2) suggests it was invented by a Deutsche Bank analyst.  [This](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/plutonomy.asp) prefers Citigroup.

Comment: (And *nomos* means "law".)

Comment: It does, but here the ending comes from *oikonomia* meaning household administration.  If the intended meaning had been laws by and for the wealthy, then the word would be plutocracy, using *kratos* (power).

Comment: Right, vogue words are often malformations. Incidentally, I don't find these descriptions of what the word was supposed to mean to be very different from plutocracy, which is broad enough in itself.